# Extremely slow performance of some MongoDB queries

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a collection of about 30K item all of which have an element called Program. "Program" is a first part of a compound index, so looking up an item with specific Program value is very fast. It is also fast to run range queries, e.g.:

```
db.MyCollection.find(
{ $and: [ { Program: { "$gte" : "K", "$lt" : "L" } }, 
{ Program: { "$gte" : "X", "$lt" : "Y" } } ] }).count();
```

The query above does not return any results because I am querying for an overlap of two non-overlaping ranges (K-L) and (X-Y)). The left range (K-L) contains about 7K items.

However if I replace the second "and" clause with "where" expression, the query execution takes ages:

```
db.MyCollection.find(
{ $and: [ { Program: { "$gte" : "K", "$lt" : "L" } }, { "$where" : "this.Program == \"Z\"" } ] }).count();
```

As you can see, the query above should also return an empty result set (range K-L is combined with Program=="Z"). I am aware of slow performance of "where", but should not Mongo first reduce potential result set by evaluating the left clause (that would result in about 7K items) and only then apply "where" check? If it does, should not processing of a few thousand items take seconds and not minutes as it does on my machine with Mongo service consuming about 3GB RAM while peforming this operation? Looks too heavy for relatively small collection.

Comment: 10gen has just released [dex](https://github.com/mongolab/dex). Maybe it can help you to setup better indexes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A bit hard to distinguish with "Mongo lab" as company name.

Comment: @SteveB dex was released by Mongo Lab, who are a 10gen partner but not actually 10gen. The blog is at http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/06/introducing-dex-the-index-bot/.

Comment: Thanks for the info on dex. However there is no more indexes to set up. I am using only one field in these queries, and it is indexed. The problem is with a "where" clause that contains JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things that you can do -

1. Use `explain()` to see what is happening on your query. `explain()` is described [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain). Use the $explain operator to return a document that describes the process and indexes used to return the query. For example -

   db.collection.find(query).explain()
2. If that doesn't return enough information, you can look at using the [Database Profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler). However, please bear in mind that this is not free and adds load itself. Within this page, you can also find some basic [notes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-OptimizingQueryPerformance) about optimising the query performance.
3. However, in your case, it all boils down to the $where operator:

   $where evaluates JavaScript and cannot take advantage of indexes. Therefore, query performance improves when you express your query using the standard MongoDB operators (e.g., $gt, $in).

   In general, you should use $where only when you can’t express your query using another operator. If you must use $where, try to include at least one other standard query operator to filter the result set. Using $where alone requires a table scan. $where, like Map Reduce, limits your [concurrency](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/How%20does%20concurrency%20work#Howdoesconcurrencywork-Javascript).

As a FYI: couple of things to note about the output from `explain()`:

- `ntoreturn` Number of objects the client requested for return from a query. For example, `findOne()`, sets ntoreturn to `limit()` sets the appropriate limit. Zero indicates no limit.
- `query` Details of the query spec.
- `nscanned` Number of objects scanned in executing the operation.
- `reslen` Query result length in bytes.
- `nreturned` Number of objects returned from query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Mark. I will run the query with "explain" option and check what it finds. Regarding where: as you are suggesting, I am combining it with a standard operator that filters results. I hope it applies "where" to the filtered results, not to the full collection. I will soon know.